# Cometd session timeout in embedded jetty

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, cometd

How can I set the sesion timeout in embedded jetty for cometd ?
Below is how I set timeout, but in server sessions it shows timeout as -1.

```
public void addCometDServletHolder(CometDServlet cometdServlet) {
    ServletHolder comet = new ServletHolder(cometdServlet);
    comet.setInitParameter("timeout", "60000"); 
    comet.setInitParameter("ws.idleTimeout", "120000");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CometD `ServerSession` `timeout` parameter controls the frequency of the CometD heartbeat messages on the `/meta/connect` channel.

If that is what you want to tune, there is a `BayeuxServer` setting, which you set in your snippet above to `60000`, and there is a `ServerSession` setting.
The former is used if the latter has not been explicitly set.

In you case, calling `ServerSession.getTimeout()` returns `-1` because you did not set it explicitly for that particular `ServerSession` object, so the `BayeuxServer` setting is used.

Note that this "timeout" controls the heartbeat message frequency, not the expiration of `ServerSession` objects on the server in case of client crash.

Please refer to the [documentation](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_java_server_configuration) for more information about the meaning of the CometD configuration parameters.

Comment: Thanks sbordet. Then could I know how to expire `ServerSession` ?

Comment: You can't expire directly a `ServerSession`, but you can disconnect it, see the `ServerSession` APIs for the correspondent method. A forced disconnect of a client from the server is typically done in chat applications to kick/ban a user. Expiration is controlled by the `maxInterval` parameter.